# Generating distinct partly-unordered permutations in Python

Tags: python, permutation, combinatorics

Given a list of length *2n*, say `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]` or `["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d"]` (elements in the list don't necessarily have to be unique), I'd like to generate all the possible distinct permutations of that list while taking into account that the order in which the element *2k* and the element *2k+1* appear doesn't matter. That means that

`["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]` and `["b", "a", "c", "d", "e", "f"]` are the same permutation, but

`["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]` and `["a", "c", "b", "d", "e", "f"]` are not.

For example, from the list `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`, the code I need would generate this sequence:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["a", "c", "b", "d"], ["a", "d", "b", "c"], ["b", "c", "a", "d"], ["b", "d", "a", "c"], ["c", "d", "a", "b"]
```

I know it's possible to do that by generating all the permutations and  keeping one of each of those that are equivalent to each other, but that's not a very efficient way to proceed, especially with larger sets. Is there a more efficient way to do that?

I wrote this code, but it's highly inefficient (keep in mind that I need to use lists with a length of up to 14):

```
from itertools import permutations


list_letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
n = int(len(list_letters) / 2)
set_distinct_perm = set()
for perm in permutations(list_letters):
    perm = list(perm)
    for i in range(n):
        perm[2*i:2*i + 2] = sorted(perm[2*i:2*i+2])
    perm = tuple(perm)
    set_distinct_perm.add(perm)
print(set_distinct_perm)
```

Comment: And what did you already tried?

Comment: I generated all the permutations, and then for each permutation, I ordered the pairs alphabetically and put the result in a set to make sure to have only one of each equivalent expression. It works, but I'm sure there's a more efficient way of doing that because it's really inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following, where we take permutations of each [2k, 2k+1] (inclusive) subsequence and then take the product of those permutations:

```py
from itertools import product, permutations

def equivalents(lst):
    perms = product(*({*permutations(lst[i:i+2])} for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)))
    return [[x for tupl in perm for x in tupl] for perm in perms] # flattening inner part

print(*equivalents('abcdef'))
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'e'] ['b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'e']
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'e']
# ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'f'] ['b', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'f']
# ['b', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'e'] ['b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
print(*equivalents('aabbef'))
# ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'f', 'e'] ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: Maybe I haven't been clear enough, but what I want are the distinct permutations, not those that are equivalent. I will edit the question to make it more clear.